# Date range filter not working properly in angular

Tags: angular, angular-filters, date-pipe

I'm using customized filter but its not working as per the requirement

```
  if(this.startdatefilter!=undefined && this.enddatefilter!=undefined){ 
      this.filterArray.push( { type:'startDate' ,value: "Start Date : "+this.startdatetime},{ type:'endDate' ,value: "End Date : "+this.enddatetime})
      filteredData = filteredData.filter(data => ((data.startDateTimeFilter)>=
        (this.startdatefilter) ) && (data.startDateTimeFilter)<=(this.enddatefilter) )   
    }
```

the date the format is - Mon Nov 11 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
startDateTimeFilter = Mon Nov 11 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) ,Thu Nov 07 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) .. goes on ..
startdatefilter = Thu Nov 07 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

I think its breaking because of date format  .. 
I tried stringifying the dates to a format 11 Nov , 2019  But didn't work ..

Any idea please help ..

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the format to dd-M-yyyy .. it worked !!